# Is there a way to create a REPL in a .py file that gives user access to it's entire context?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I can make a simple REPL that parses input and handles it according to customized logic. I was wondering if and how one can create a REPL inside a .py file similar to when you open python in a terminal, but includes access to the properties, methods and classes of one's file. For example they could type print('hello world') and it would do that or they could call cpu.ram_write() below.

```
# Should be obvious what I am doing here. There's a CPU class above with a few methods and properties. 
cpu = CPU()
print(cpu.ram_read(4))
cpu.ram_write(5,4)
print(cpu.ram_read(4))

# This is where I want the REPL
while True:
    x = input("Enter a command: ")
    if x == 'q':
        quit()
    try:
        x
    except:
        print("error")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to spawn a REPL from wherever you are in a python program.

```
import code

# launch a REPL
code.interact(local=globals())
```

[Reference docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html)